# ATEN saving and export, import problem

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded [aten-1.8](http://www.projectaten.org/) and compiled and executed it in Ubuntu 13.1. But when running window opens and gives me the following message:

Filters could not be found.
No import/export will be possible.
Set the environment variable ATENDATA to point to Aten's data directory (e.g. 'export ATENDATA=/usr/local/aten/data'), or run with --atendata .

I did set environment variable ATENDATA to point to Aten's data directory, but same problem remains. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in aten.

If you encounter a bug in any of the codes supplied here, think you have found a mistake or, after reading the relevant manual, can't find the information you're looking for, please email support@projectaten.net with details of the problem / issue, and I will try to help as best I can.

Source: http://www.projectaten.org/